# On which scenarios firewall is not supported by the nodes?

Tags: minio, jelastic

I'm trying to run a Minio Cluster using the Jelastic template, however when attempting to activate the firewall on one of the nodes I'm greeted with the message "Firewall is not supported on this node."

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE8Ab.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firewall is only supported on official images from Jelastic.

When you use a custom docker image for your node, you won't be able to use the Jelastic Firewall on it. You have to manually configure the iptables.

Comment: More info can be found in the official documentation
https://docs.jelastic.com/custom-firewall/#container-firewall-management-via-jelastic-ui:
"excluding custom Docker- and Windows-based containers"